# How does one find if $x^3 + 3x^2 - 8x + 12 = 0 \bmod 5k$ has any root for $k$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Actually I want to show that there is no solution to the cubic equation for any value of $k$.  I have tried some values of $k$, and I want to see if it can be shown to be true for all $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could show $n^3+3n^2-8n+12\not\equiv0\pmod 5$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: I have done that for k=1,2,3 but i would like a general proof for any k.

Comment: if $5\nmid n^3+3n^2-8n+12$, then surely $5k\nmid n^3+3n^2+8n+12$

Comment: I see your point.  Thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sir, what is the $∤$ operator? What does it mean?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it is a kinda Unicode character meaning "Does Not Divide". Thanks, sir. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2224 I've learned it by you. I didn't know it before.

Comment: Yes, `$\nmid$` ($\nmid$) means does not divide

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

To make the computations of @Tanner  easier, you can use the fact that
$$n^3+3n^2-8n+12=$$
$$n^3+3n^2+3n+1-11n+11=$$
$$(n+1)^3-11(n-1)$$